# Drawing area graph in directX

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, directx

I have an MFC application to draw graph using DirectX. Now I have to add the feature to draw the area graph in DirectX.

Now my application draws like this..

[image]

I want to include the feature to my graph to look like this..

[image]

here I have to fill the graph area with some color.

I have tried DrawPrimitive(). but this could be used to draw the Triangle, rectangle. but in my application I would like to draw graph with random data points.

Is it possible to achieve in DirectX..?

Kindly someone provide your suggestions.

Comment: If you only need 2D drawing, Direct2D is much easier to work with than the full API.

Comment: Thank you Roger. I need in 2D only. I will read about direct2D and check.

Comment: You can fill the area using **polygon triangulation**. Refer http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf .There are so many pre-written examples and papers. eg:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319399/Terrain-Rendering  and  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492435/Delaunay-Triangulation-For-Fast-Mesh-Generation   .   2d specific triangulation  https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/...

Comment: If you [look at path geometries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee264309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first, you may find it an easy way to fill the shape by defining the border path and filling that rather than drawing lots of individual lines.

Comment: @Roger and Dharani: for using path geometrics or Direct2D, I should have Windows SDk v7.0 or v7.1 it seems. I have SDK v6.0 only. So I'm getting d2d1.h missing error. Is it possible to use Direct2D with SDK v6.0?

Comment: No, you need a later SDK, but if your target OS is Win7 or higher then there should be no problem - just install and build against that SDK. Even Vista SP2 (I think) supported D2D. What version of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: @Roger: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 in windows 7, SDK v6.0.

Comment: I have d3d9.h, d3d9helper.h instead of d2d1.h and d2d1helper.h.. and dwrite is not available in v6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u need 2d graph's alone Direct2D is a great option,But if you insist on going to 3D for greater animation and illustrative purposes you can uses OpenGL.There are plenty of custom controls for graph illustration purposes based on OpenGL.

For eg:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4346/D-Graph-ActiveX-Control

Opengl has greater flexibility and can serve your needs better since it is of open source.

hope this helps and Good Luck

Comment: Point of order, [OpenGL is **not** open source](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_OpenGL_Open_Source.3F).

Comment: @RogerRowland: Thank you for correcting me,I got confused with it's numerous extensions assuming OpenGL as open source.My bad.

Comment: @Dharani: Thank you Dharani. I need my graph in 2D only. I will study about Direct2D and try to solve this issue.

Comment: @San: Okay.Best of luck with it.